# Privoxy, block some clients(IP addresses) accessing certain web site but other clients are allowed

Tags: privoxy

Is it possible block some clients accessing certain web site while other clients are allowed?

if yes what is the configuration?

ACL can't help and I had not any success with {+client-header-tagger{client-ip-address}},all samples i've found for {+client-header-tagger{client-ip-address}} is just for forwarding not blocking.